# Happy Holidays All and Thank you note

Tags: discussion

Yes this is subjective; however, this is just a thank you note to the gis.stackexchange community, as I've learned over the past few months ways, tools, and methods that simplified my life and dramatically increased my productivity, whether through splendid answers to my questions or reading through comments and answers on other questions.

Happy Holidays wherever you are and have a cartographic amazing new year

Answer (score 1):

Happy Holidays to you as well, where ever you are on the globe.